# Computing Gaussian Curvature Given First Fundamental Form - Verification

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I'm given the following first fundamental form for a surface:

$$ds^2=(2+v^2)du^2+2(2+uv)dudv+(2+u^2)dv^2.$$

By Brioschi's Formula, the Gaussian curvature, as I've calculated it, is:

$$K=2(u-v)^2/(3u^2v^2-2u^2+16uv-2v^2+12)^2.$$

I've double checked the computation and made sure I correctly applied the formula.

The answer choices are: $0,1,uv,(u-v)^2,2(u-v)^2$.

This is not among the answer choices on this short computation assignment I was given. Perhaps there is an error among the answer choices. If this is not the correct answer, could someone demonstrate the proper way to compute it?

Comment: It may or may not be helpful to rewrite the denominator as \begin{align}
3u^2v^2-2u^2+16uv-2v^2+12 &= 3(u^2v^2+4uv+4)-2(u^2-2uv+v^2)\\
&= 3(uv+2)^2-2(u-v)^2
\end{align}

Comment: The answer choices are $0$, $1$, $uv$, $(u-v)^2$, $2(u-v)^2$. I think it is most likely he neglected to place the denominator among the choices, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some simple manipulation before contacting him.

Comment: A potential error that you may or may not have made: the denominator in the Brioschi formula is \begin{align}
(EG-F^2)^2 &= \big((2+v^2)(2+u^2) - (2+uv)^2\big)^2\\
&=\big(4+2(u^2+v^2)+u^2v^2 - (4+4uv+u^2v^2)\big)^2\\
&= (2u^2+2v^2-4uv)^2 = 4(u-v)^4.
\end{align}

Comment: I just realized the error. I had been using $2F$ in place of $F$.

Comment: Glad we were able to find it!